# Summarizing values in column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics

In my vector field I would like to summarize all values in a column, how yo do so? If I right-click in the attribute table it is possible to choose summarize, but if I do so and select the column I want to include the values in the column is not summarized I only get a Sum_output. In the sum_output I have a new table with the selected column but no summary!

In my case I have created a buffer zone and want to know the length of it. The length of the buffer zone is divided into the areas where the buffer zone is. So I have around 1000 of pieces of buffer length. How can I summarize these pieces?

Comment: The feature class with buffer zone, is it a polyline or polygon shapefile? Even if you can calculate the length of a polygon, it makes much more sense to do so with a line.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool:

> Calculates summary statistics for field(s) in a table.

Set your case field to be the column that represents the different areas.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions to get statistics for a shapefile (as mentioned by @danb). But first you probably need to calculate the length/area first in a field.

1. Create a new field ([Add field function](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000))
2. Right click the header of that field --> Calculate geometry. Choose length/area depending on what you need.
3. The field gets populated with length/area values which you can summarize using the above mentioned function. Chose SUM for Statistics type.

This will give you a table, not a feature class, where the result is displayed (which can be viewed in the Table of contents --> List by source).